# Pass a dependency instance to a factory method parameter to make Ninject use it within the resolution

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have an abstract factory which creates some service represented by `IService` interface. In the factory I have two `Create` methods, because at one of them I allow the consumer to pass an existing `IServiceLogger` instance to be used by the constructed service tree.

```
public interface IMyServiceFactory {
  IMyService Create(IServiceLogger loggerInstance);
  IMyService Create();
}
```

Because an `IServiceLogger` should be shared among the service tree, I use the `InCallScope` when binding it to a concrete implementation.

How can I implement this scenario with Ninject? I've tried the following approaches.

**1. Manually create a factory implementation**

```
internal class MyServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory {

  private IResolutionRoot _kernel;

  public MyServiceFactory  

  public IMyService Create(IServiceLogger loggerInstance) {
    // what should go here? how can I pass the existing instance to Ninject Get method and make Ninject to use it for the whole resolution tree, just as it were created by Ninject and used as InCallScope?
  }

  // this one is trivial...
  pulbic IMyService Create() {
    return _kernel.Get<IMyService>();
  }
}
```

UPDATE

Actually I've found a messy and not too safe way for this. I can get the current bindings via `GetBindings`, then `Rebind` `IServiceLogger` `ToConstant`, then `Get` the `IMyService` instance, and finally restore the original bindings with `AddBinding`. I don't like it, it feels stinky and what's worse, it's not thread-safe, because another thread can request for a `IMyService` in the middle of this code and hence use the local temporary binding.

**2. Use Ninject.Extensions.Factory**

Just use the `ToFactory` binding, but that's not working, because it just tries to use the parameter as a simple constructor argument (if applicable), and not as an object for the whole resolution tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

While my original answer gave me a working solution, by an accidental InteliSense navigation I've just found that there is a built-in tool for exactly this issue. I just have to use the built-in `TypeMatchingArgumentInheritanceInstanceProvider` which does this, and even more, because there are no more needs for naming conventions due to the parameter type matching.

It would be good to have a more detailed documentation about these options, or maybe it's just me who can't find it currently.

---

*ORIGINAL ANSWER*

I tried a few ways, and ended up with a slightly different, kind of a convention based approach utilizing Ninject's context parameter inheritance.

The convention is used at constructor argument naming through the dependency tree. For example whenever an `IServiceLogger` instance is injected to a service class, the argument should be called `serviceLogger`.

With the above convention in mind, I've tested the following approach. Firstly I've implemented a custom instance provider for the factory extension. This custom provider overrides the mechanism for creating constructor parameters for the context to let the developer specify several named arguments which should be set as inherited. This way all the parameters with the specified names will inherit through the whole request graph during the get operation.

```
public class ParameterInheritingInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    private readonly List<string> _parametersToInherit = new List<string>();

    public ParameterInheritingInstanceProvider(params string[] parametersToInherit)
    {
        _parametersToInherit.AddRange(parametersToInherit);
    }

    protected override IConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        var constructorArgumentArray = new IConstructorArgument[parameters.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Length; ++i)
            constructorArgumentArray[i] = new ConstructorArgument(parameters[i].Name, arguments[i], _parametersToInherit.Contains(parameters[i].Name));
        return constructorArgumentArray;
    }
}
```

Then after at binding configuration I just threw it in with the corresponding parameter name.

```
kernel.Bind<IMyServiceFactory>().ToFactory(() => new ParameterInheritingInstanceProvider("serviceLogger"));
```

Finally I reviewed parameter naming, and for exampled changed `loggerInstance` in the factory interface to `serviceLogger` to match the convention.

This solution is still not the nicest one as it has several limitations.

1. It is error prone. One can make bugs which are hard to track by not keeping the naming convention, because currently it silently fails if the convention does not match. This could be improved probably, I'll think about it later.
2. It handles only constructor injection, however this should not be a big issue as that's the suggested technique. For example I almost never do other kind of injections.

Answer (score 0):

I would give more control to the Kernel of Ninject and do not create a class for the factory at all.
And use Func binding in Ninject like this:

```
Bind<Func<IMyService>>().ToMethod(s => CreateService);
```

By binding of the ILoggerService or not binding this you can controll centrally whether you have logger or not in your service.(try by just comment it out)

Here implementation of the Bootstrapper:

```
 public class Bootstrapper
    {
        private IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel();

        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            _kernel.Bind<MyStuff>().ToSelf();
            _kernel.Bind<IServiceLogger>().To<ServiceLogger>();
            _kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>();

            _kernel.Bind<Func<IMyService>>().ToMethod(s => CreateService);
        }

        public IKernel Kernel
        {
            get
            {
                return _kernel;
            }
            set
            {
                _kernel = value;
            }
        }

        private IMyService CreateService()
        {


            if(_kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IServiceLogger)).Any())
            {
                return _kernel.Get<IMyService>(new ConstructorArgument("logger", _kernel.Get<IServiceLogger>()));
            }

            return _kernel.Get<IMyService>();
        }
    }
```

Implementation of consumer class for the factory:

```
 internal class MyStuff
    {
        private readonly Func<IMyService> _myServiceFactory;

        public MyStuff(Func<IMyService> myServiceFactory)
        {
            _myServiceFactory = myServiceFactory;

            _myServiceFactory.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Simple implementation of MyService:

```
 internal class MyService
        :IMyService
    {
        public MyService()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("with no parameters");
        }

        public MyService(IServiceLogger logger)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("with logger parameters");
        }
    }
```

Simple **ServiceLogger**:

```
internal class ServiceLogger
        :IServiceLogger
    {
        public ServiceLogger()
        {

        }
    }

    internal interface IServiceLogger
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What you've described is quite straightforward, and wouldn't even need any code IMO because as far as simple one-level constructor arguments go, the Factory extension does the job (as I mentioned in my post). The problem comes when 1: a logger MIGHT be optional 2. a logger should be used by the complete service tree, not just on the top-level. I've found a solution however, I'm gonna post it soon.

Comment: Oh OK. Then I would recommend to use conditional binding, which is quite powerfull in ninject.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this was asked a long time ago but I was looking to do the same sort  of thing myself and finally worked out that you can use the `IParameter` array passed to the `Get()` method to specify a `ContructorArgument` to use only for the current `Get()` call. This allowed me to use a specific constructor value when creating a Hangfire Job allowing the Hangfire job to use a different database connection on each invocation if required.

```
                    EnvironmentName forcedEnv = new EnvironmentName() { Name = dbName };

                    // For this instantiation, set the 'envName' parameter to be the one we've specified for this job
                    var instance = ResolutionExtensions.Get((IResolutionRoot) _kernel, jobType, 
                        new IParameter[] {new ConstructorArgument("envName", forcedEnv, true)});

                    return instance;
```

By setting the `shouldInherit` value to `true` you can ensure the value gets passed down the resolution chain. So it get's passed to any objects in the dependency tree that use that argument (but only for this particular instantiation).